# Reducing Gaps in dynamically generated TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I'm working on a ASP.NET application that uses the in-built Treeview. For some reason, the vertical space between the nodes will not reduce no matter what I try in the CSS.

**The nodes are dynamically generated, see the example bellow:**

[image]

**The tree is generated using:**

```
<asp:TreeView ID="rcmTree" runat="server" CssClass="treeView" ShowLines="true"></asp:TreeView>
```

**And then the CSS Code I have is:**

```
.treeNode {
  text-indent: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.treeNode a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.treeView tr {
  margin-top: -25px;
}

.treeView {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

#rcmTree td div {
  height: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - I had to change the Doctype to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```